# How to use Phonegap Plugin in my Index.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I installed the cordova Download plugin from the Cordova Plugin registry via the Cli.
My problem is that the plugin has no documentation hence I can't figure out how to use the plugin in my `Index.html`.

I tried calling it like this, but it did not work:

```
window.plugins.DownLoad.downLoad(url,fileName,false,success,failure);
```

I've posted the `Download.js` file of the plugin below:

```
 cordova.define("com.cmpsoft.mobile.plugin.download.DownLoad", function(require,  exports, module) {

 var DownLoad = function() {};

 DownLoad.prototype.downLoad = function(url,fileName,openFlag,successCallback,   failureCallback) {
if(typeof(cordova)!='undefined'){
    return cordova.exec(function(obj){
        if(successCallback == null ) return;
        if(typeof successCallback == 'function'){
            successCallback(obj);
        }
       }, function(obj){
        if(failureCallback == null ) return;
        if(typeof failureCallback == 'function'){
            failureCallback(obj);
        }
     },  'DownLoad', 'DownLoad', [url,fileName,openFlag]);
   }
 };
 var download = new DownLoad();

  module.exports = download;});
```

Comment: following the code above you should be able to use this plugin like this: download.downLoad(url,fileName,false,success,failure); But note that will only work after the deviceReady event has triggered.

Comment: Yeah David,I tried the above code but it did not work.I also made sure i called It after device ready. You can install the plugin from here    com.cmpsoft.mobile.plugin.download

Comment: which version of phonegap are you using?

Comment: This JS file above does not appear to be formatted for 3.0+

Comment: found the plugin at the cordova plugin registry http://plugins.cordova.io/  All plugins there are 3.0+ compatible

Comment: Its working!.This how to use it   window.fastgoDownLoad.downLoad(url,fileName,false,success,failure);